# What is wrong with this pagination?

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong with this code? When I click on 'Next' button it shows empty page and broke my web design? I've trying to figure it out all day but no luck.

```
            <?php
        if(isset($_GET['joke_id'])){
            $joke_id = $_GET['joke_id'];
            $qry = "SELECT * FROM joke WHERE joke_cat = '$joke_id'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $qry) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));

            $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
            if (!$line) echo '';
            $previd = -1;
            $currid = $line[0];
            if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                $previous_ids = array();
                do {
                    $previous_ids[] = $line[0];
                    $currid = $line[0];
                    if ($currid == $_GET['id']) break;
                    $previd = end($previous_ids);
                    $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
                } while ($line);
            }

            if ($line) {
                echo "<div id=\"box\">";
                echo nl2br($line['text']) . "<br /><br />";
                echo "</div>";
            }
            else echo 'Is empty<br/>'; **<------ HERE**


            if ($previd > -1)
                echo '<a href="cat_vic.php?cat_id='.$joke_id.'?id='.$previd.'" class="prev_pic"><span>Prev</span></a>';
            echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);

            $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);

            $query = "select * from joke WHERE joke_cat = '$joke_id' order by RAND() LIMIT 1";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
                echo '<a href="cat_vic.php?cat_id='.$joke_id.'?id='.$row['id'].'"class="random">Random</a>';
            }
            echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);
            if ($line) echo '<a href="cat_vic.php?cat_id='.$joke_id.'?id='.$line[0].'" class="next_pic"><span>Next</span></a><br /><br />';
            echo "</div>\r";
        }
        ?>
```

Also on the line `else echo 'Is empty<br/>';` doesn't matter if there is something .. always shows me 'Is empty'..

UPDATE:
databases are:
joke

```
id
text
date
joke_cat
```

and `cat_joke` is

```
joke_id
joke_name
```

Comment: what you see with var_dump($line) ,,,just incase try to add open and close braces for if condition

Comment: var_dump($line) return empty and broken page also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
echo '<a href="cat_vic.php?cat_id='.$joke_id.'?id='.$row['id'].'"class="random">Random</a>';
```

**To:** not **?** after cat_id='.$joke_id.' you need to change **&**

```
echo '<a href="cat_vic.php?cat_id='.$joke_id.'&id='.$row['id'].'"class="random">Random</a>';
```

**Note:** also change next and prev code also...

Comment: Same thing .. blank page

Comment: you pass url in cat_id = $joke_id but joke_id ='$joke_id' then only pagination if  condition executed...

Comment: Strange... before to ask here I tried with `cat_vic.php?joke_id='.$joke_id.'` and doesn't worked .. and now is working.

Comment: So the real problem was that I used `?` but `&` and `cat_id='.$joke_id.'` instead of `joke_id='.$joke_id.'` . Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Your last assigment to `$line` is `null` .Therefore you should check in your `if` not `$line` but the `$previous_ids[]` or `$currid` or the others.

Comment: But how is possible to be null.. I'm sure that there is data in table?

Comment: You are fetching data and assigning to other variables. What you are doing is you are fetching until no result is received. In that case, **the last** result from the query is null where you make your last assignment to `$line`.

Comment: To be more clear, your do while loop gets data until `$line = null` which means that there are no more rows to retrieve. So at the end, `$line` is `null`.